# Como criar teclas de atalho

Tags: sublime-text-3

Alguém sabe como criar uma telha de atalho para inserir um texto de minha referencia. Porque ficar copiando e colando todas as vezes e complicado!

Answer (score 1):

Já aprendi:

```
{"keys": ["shift+alt+enter"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "escreva seu texto"}}
```